# Exposing Database data via OData

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, azure, odata

I am looking for a way to expose a finite amount of data to another company via a OData web service.
I am fully up to date to creating the WCF Data Service and linking to Entity Framework. I have also uploaded the service to an azure web site and it is fully available via the url.
I'm a little fuzzy on what happens in between and how I can query the data as I keep getting a  'The underlying provider failed on Open'
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I am assuming its a security issue.
This is on my local sql server exposing out into the internet so in theory anyone can access the data.
Thanks in advance
Scott

Comment: I used a "File SQL DB - attach" in my local copy.  When I tried to upload it, I also got security issues. I attached the MDF to an existing SQL instance and changed my EF connection string to point to the actual running copy of DB.  Sorted it out for me.

Comment: With the WCF, you need to also remember to look in the Windows application and system event log.  I found some of my issues there.

Comment: was your connection string to your local or did it have the external ip? cheers

Comment: Yes, local.  But initially it wanted to attach on the fly (like the new sql templates are done).  I just used a "normal" connection string linking to an actual SQL instance and DB.   (.\SQLEXPRESS), etc.

Comment: still stuck. will keep trying to open up the ports/server somehow

Comment: Turn off your firewall (temporary) for the test to see that that is not the problem.

Comment: just got home and I can access my sql server instance via my external ip so there are no firewall problem. wonder if any settings on the config wcf file or maybe azure web site. thanks again

Comment: just tried it again with external IP and I got a hit. thanks for you help

Comment: Pleasure. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Opening firewall etc. and using my external IP has solved it. Scott